# Calculate the Date difference in javascript with timer update

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, timer, difference

If you have two dates lets say dt1 and dt2.
How will you calculate the difference between them.

Here is the working example for your help:

```
var dt1;
var dt2;
$(document).ready(function () {
    dt1 = new Date();
    dt2 = new Date();
    setInterval(function () {
        dt2.setSeconds(dt2.getSeconds() + 1);

        var diff = GetDateDiff(dt1, dt2);
        $("#dtDIV").html(diff);

    }, 1000);
});

function GetDateDiff(a, b) {
    var msInDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    var d1 = a.getTime();
    var d2 = b.getTime();

    var mlseconds = d2 - d1;

    mlseconds = mlseconds / 1000;
    var seconds = Math.floor(mlseconds % 60);
    mlseconds = mlseconds / 60;
    var minutes = Math.floor(mlseconds % 60);
    mlseconds = mlseconds / 60;
    var hours = Math.floor(mlseconds % 24);
    var days = Math.floor(mlseconds / 24);

    return days + ' days, ' + hours + ' hours, ' + minutes + ' minutes, and ' + seconds + ' seconds';
}
```

Full working example: http://goo.gl/5NE45o

Happy Coding !!! 
Ambuj

Comment: So, what's the question? Does this work? Not work? What do you want from us?

Comment: If you have a full working example, what's the question ?

Comment: I searched it all over to find the difference, then after doing calculations, I found the solution, so I thought this will help others, who are looking for the similar problem.